# How to send data in viewpager fragments by clicking on button from one fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android

I need to pass data from one fragment to another fragment in view pager android. As per my requirement I have 3 fragments in my view pager. In the second fragment, I have the next button. So once I click the next button in second fragment it should redirect to third fragment. Now the issue is the data in second fragment should pass to third fragment once we click on the next button. I tried saving the data in shared preferences. Data from second fragment to third fragment is coming if I swipe the screen. But if I click on next button then it is redirecting to third fragment but data is not coming to third screen.

```
Code:

SecondFragment:
  tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
                    edt.putString("facebook_id", "hhhhhhhhhh");
                    edt.commit();

                    ViewPagerFragment.pager.setCurrentItem(2);

                }
            });

ThirdFragment:

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_total, container, false);

        TextView tv =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mtext);

        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String id = pref.getString("facebook_id", "empty");

        tv.setText(id);


        return v;
    }
C
```

an anybody please tell me how to resolve this issue. I need to redirect to third fragment only by clicking the next button in second fragment. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I think the reason you are not getting any data is because your fragment is already initialized i.e onCreateView of 3rd fragment has been already called before you clicked next

Comment: ok..can you tell me how can I pass the data on next click action..Please help me..I am trying this from 1 week but no luck

Comment: what you can do is, on click of next pass the callback to your activity and from there access the viewpager and get the instance of your 3rd fragment and use it to pass the data to your fragment by creating a simple function and invoking it using the instance of 3rd fragment